# What does 不 at the end of a sentence (e.g. 更新速度可以快点不) mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does 不 at the end of a sentence mean?

For example,

更新速度可以快点不

The context is somebody complaining about updating site content so slow.

Does it mean "Can update speed be quicker" ?

Comment: cf。＂现代汉语词典＂：不（４）（方）用在句末表示疑问，跟反复问句的作用相等：他现在身体好～？Note ＂（方）＂which may explain absence in most Chinese grammars.

Comment: I have always thought it means "or not?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, your translation is right.

可以…不 ～=  可不可以…

Usually used to form an alternative question.

可以快点不～=可不可以快点?
这个可以吃不～=这个可不可以吃? Is this eatable?